# iOS - extracting data from a plist not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

This is a routine exercise. I have done it a number of times in my current project and it has worked fine. I copied the code line for line, same initializations. My plist data goes into a dictionary but then it does not go into its respective arrays in their initializations. I have a method called initArraysPlist

```
-(void)initArraysPlist{
NSString *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"trainerProfile" ofType:@"plist"];
// Load the file content and read the data into arrays
NSDictionary *dict1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path1];

trainerNames = [dict1 objectForKey:@"Names"];
trainerIcons = [dict1 objectForKey:@"Icons"];
trainerFactSheet= [dict1 objectForKey:@"Fact Sheet"];
trainerFocus = [dict1 objectForKey:@"Focus"];
trainerContactInfo= [dict1 objectForKey:@"Contact Info"];
```

}

Ive done this a few times and it currently works in my code. all the values are correct. Ive checked it many times. when

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code it may be helpful to you

```
// Read plist from bundle and get Root Dictionary out of it

NSDictionary *dictRoot = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"]];

// Your dictionary contains an array of dictionary
// Now pull an Array out of it.

NSArray *arrayList = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[dictRoot objectForKey:@"catlist"]];

// Now a loop through Array to fetch single Item from catList which is Dictionary

[arrayList enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {

    // Fetch Single Item
    // Here obj will return a dictionary

     NSLog(@"Category name : %@",[obj valueForKey:@"category_name"]);
     NSLog(@"Category id   : %@",[obj valueForKey:@"cid"]);
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read the comments for the each line.

```
  NSString *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"trainerProfile" ofType:@"plist"]; // **check if your plist is actually added in Bundle.If its there move to second line , if not then add plist in bundle.**

   NSDictionary *dict1 = [[NSDictionary alloc]    initWithContentsOfFile:path1];// **if plist is added in bundle , then check if you are getting value for dict1 . If no then you might be making some mistake in plist structure.**
```

For more clarifications please post your plist if possible.